# Замостить изображение цветом CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Скажите пожалуйста, как добиться такого эффекта? Нужно чтобы при наведении на картинку, она заливалась цветом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как этот кусок карты.

Answer (score 6):

1. Делаешь картинку в svg.
2. Складываешь интересующие регионы в группы `g` с некоторым классом.
3. По этому классу на `:hover` в css меняешь `fill` для `path`.

Примерно так (класс не стал делать, т. к. карту нагуглил - и так его ещё ужимать пришлось):

```css
html, body, svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

.c {fill: #fff;}
.d {fill: #c30;}
.e {fill: #8b0000;}
.f {fill: gold;}
.g {fill: #f66;}

path:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="500 400 150 700" class="a"><path d="M518.33 776.69C518.33 776.69 518.71 781.39 519.06 783.14 520.42 783.3 521.8 783.41 523.17 783.55 523.3 785.04 523.38 786.52 523.49 788.01 524.86 788.96 526.21 789.93 527.52 790.97 527.25 793.09 527.19 795.27 526.53 797.32 523.99 799.56 520.86 801.05 518.39 803.37 518.23 805.46 519.03 807.49 519.37 809.54 517.17 810.2 516.65 812.47 515.93 814.36 513.82 814.17 511.75 813.73 509.65 813.58 508.85 816.35 507.9 819.07 507 821.82 502.97 825.19 498.27 827.71 494.25 831.12 495.16 832.79 496.28 834.33 497.29 835.94 496.2 837.35 495.1 838.76 493.87 840.06 492.76 838.45 492.07 836.5 490.59 835.17 486.56 835.94 482.63 837.34 478.8 838.82 478.78 840.21 478.81 841.62 478.8 843.02 476.41 843.94 474.04 844.97 471.54 845.58 470.4 842.45 469.42 839.27 468.3 836.13 469.8 835.44 471.3 834.72 472.73 833.87 471.45 831.34 469.21 829.48 467.84 827.03 467.28 824.48 470.2 824.34 471.96 824.25 471.89 822.46 471.48 820.72 471.1 818.99 472.15 818.06 473.69 817.4 474.05 815.93 474.59 813.48 475.16 810.84 474.2 808.42 474.83 807.9 475.87 807.02 476.5 806.5 476.5 806.5 475.95 804.67 474.53 802.47 472.35 799.03 470.91 795.17 468.63 791.79 463.5 787.8 456.09 786.53 452.56 780.64 452.63 778.73 453.25 776.89 453.44 775 450.12 772.65 446.72 770.42 443.2 768.37 445.21 765.14 447.98 762.45 450.16 759.34 450.66 758.71 450.7 757.91 450.86 757.16 445.5 754.89 439.87 753.28 434.58 750.83 434.76 747.79 434.97 744.75 435.21 741.71 436.47 740.7 438.91 740.15 438.51 738.09 437.91 732.98 437.6 727.78 436.53 722.74 434.44 720.94 431.83 719.91 429.51 718.46 428.14 717.54 426.16 716.92 425.78 715.11 424.75 711.28 423.87 707.41 422.94 703.56 422.01 700.53 425.15 697.66 423.4 694.73 425.62 691.35 427.69 687.88 430.1 684.64 431.71 685.47 433.44 686.35 434.34 688.02 437.92 693.88 441.69 699.62 445.21 705.52 445.92 706.43 446.44 707.98 447.75 708.07 452.02 707.79 456.24 707.04 460.49 706.52 462.49 706.34 464.65 705.55 466.55 706.59 468.91 707.68 470.16 708.08 471.83 708.86 473.13 709.42 473.18 708.88 473.96 708.1 474.45 707.6 475.07 706.53 475.58 705.79 477.18 702.97 478.9 700.21 480.63 697.46 481.73 695.49 484.66 696.26 485.88 694.42 486.94 693.02 488 691.73 488.96 690.15 489.88 688.53 496.77 692.67 497.4 690.29 498.51 687.72 499.98 685.81 501.41 683.78 502.75 684.1 504.52 684.27 507.43 683.95 509.39 684.54 506.73 687.78 507.1 690.06 511.23 689.79 514.1 688.29 516.82 687.51 519.61 683.8 522.96 680.73 524.5 679.77 525.52 678.26 527.48 673.54 528.09 674.08 531.7 677.71 533.62 687.67 537.23 691.3 538.76 692.87 545.11 680.24 546.97 681.39 548.07 682.06 549.17 682.75 550.18 683.55 551.66 684.79 553.48 685.48 555.11 686.48 556.27 687.17 556.78 688.48 557.35 689.64 560.71 697.2 564.12 704.73 567.56 712.26 568.15 713.53 568.82 714.87 568.68 716.32 568.5 719.51 568.11 722.68 567.9 725.86 567.91 727.03 567.27 728.04 566.53 728.9 561.46 734.59 556.32 740.21 551.27 745.93 550.33 746.73 549.79 748.56 551.14 749.25 556.07 752.38 561.39 754.88 566.33 758 564.95 759.82 563.71 761.77 562.08 763.38 559.4 764.69 556.32 764.53 553.53 765.42 551.9 767.37 551.9 770.18 551.17 772.55 548.14 771.56 544.94 771.85 541.82 771.83 538.48 771.84 534.42 772.07 531.08 772.04 528.01 772.16 518.33 776.69 518.33 776.69Z" class="d"></path><path d="M542.38 876.76C544.95 875.18 548.07 875.82 550.92 875.82 551.29 877.09 551.11 878.71 552.23 879.63 553.85 881.02 555.46 882.42 557.2 883.66 557.99 884.36 559.05 883.92 559.96 883.77 563.1 883 566.18 881.89 569.42 881.6 570.32 883.82 571.23 886.05 571.97 888.34 570.52 890.44 568.56 892.14 567.18 894.3 565.65 899.11 563.73 903.8 562.05 908.56 561.35 910.86 559.44 912.68 557.26 913.59 555.1 913.26 553.34 911.69 551.29 910.97 549.67 912.35 548.18 913.87 546.64 915.33 545.61 914.04 544.68 912.67 543.77 911.29 542.5 911.14 541.23 911.02 539.97 910.88 539.46 909.44 539.04 907.97 538.34 906.62 536.42 906.51 535.58 908.85 534.26 909.95 534.19 908.51 534.98 906.58 533.46 905.65 529.72 902.99 525.66 900.78 521.96 898.07 521.69 895.47 523.66 893.19 523.81 890.61 523.36 888.69 522.49 886.91 521.92 885.03 524.9 884.4 528.04 884.57 530.96 883.65 534.9 881.58 538.53 878.98 542.38 876.76Z" class="e"></path><path d="M442.25 873.79C442.25 873.79 442.13 875.02 442.09 876.17 442.08 877.33 442.76 878.94 442.76 878.94 446.23 886.35 449.35 893.91 453.13 901.17 452.3 902.09 451.47 903.03 450.67 903.97 451.71 908.43 454.25 912.59 454.05 917.3 453.99 918.66 454.19 920.12 453.64 921.42 450.43 923.07 446.85 923.87 443.65 925.56 444.81 932.83 445.9 940.1 446.97 947.38 447.2 949.24 448.17 951.57 446.19 952.83 442.59 951.1 439.26 948.91 435.71 947.12 434.08 946.21 432.24 947.02 430.53 947.18 428.49 947.56 427 947.71 427 947.71 425.67 948.17 425.46 948.93 426.09 949.97 427.74 952.34 429.19 954.83 430.75 957.26 431.73 957.4 432.73 957.54 433.72 957.67 433.22 959.72 432.7 961.79 432.52 963.91 433.52 964.05 434.53 964.18 435.54 964.33 436.28 967.44 436.81 970.62 437.73 973.7 438.63 973.53 439.53 973.29 440.45 973.2 441.36 973.82 441.93 974.78 442.57 975.67 437.73 977.76 432.18 976.97 427.25 978.67 425.68 981.6 426.38 985.19 425.63 988.38 416.28 987.45 406.99 985.89 397.65 984.84 396.6 984.76 395.44 984.6 394.53 985.26 393.75 986.84 393.36 988.57 392.8 990.24 385.85 986.09 379.3 981.33 372.47 976.99 369.54 975.37 366.02 975.92 362.9 974.94 362.9 974.94 360.72 974.67 360.09 975.07 356 976.72 352.04 978.78 347.68 979.64 344.99 980.31 342.25 980.77 339.6 981.56 336.72 982.3 335.62 985.44 333.39 987.11 331.36 987.7 329.13 987.25 327.15 988.04 326.04 988.74 325.66 990.09 325.12 991.21 324.07 993.8 322.73 996.26 321.7 998.86 321.06 1000.22 321.85 1001.65 322.12 1003 320.81 1004.27 318.65 1005.03 318.14 1006.89 318.78 1008.72 320.53 1009.89 321.73 1011.36 321.15 1013.05 320.7 1014.83 319.77 1016.38 317.68 1017.7 315.06 1017.74 312.88 1018.89 312.19 1019.23 311.92 1020.11 312.01 1020.85 312.2 1022.95 312.53 1025.05 312.57 1027.18 308.86 1026.62 305.2 1025.77 301.54 1024.95 297.85 1024.37 297.84 1019.03 294.18 1018.37 290.66 1017.68 287.08 1017.23 283.56 1016.54 283.2 1015.57 282.96 1014.55 282.43 1013.67 281.7 1013.22 280.91 1012.92 280.15 1012.57 279.38 1012.22 277.69 1010.72 277.97 1011.77 278.25 1012.82 278.67 1013.91 278.49 1015.03 277.89 1015.77 277.16 1016.4 276.45 1017.04 274.43 1015.26 272.65 1013.23 270.64 1011.46 269.47 1010.39 267.79 1010.65 266.35 1010.6 264.13 1010.64 261.92 1010.49 259.71 1010.7 256.82 1011.41 255.11 1015.05 251.85 1014.54 247.9 1014.46 243.83 1012.99 239.94 1013.9 237.5 1017.29 236.65 1021.59 234.45 1025.13 231.71 1026.57 228.4 1026.13 225.53 1027.18 223.02 1028.72 222.81 1032.23 220.52 1033.97 217.63 1035.34 214.33 1035.72 211.51 1037.26 211.3 1037.59 210.86 1038.27 210.65 1038.61 212.47 1040.51 214.8 1041.87 216.46 1043.94 213.88 1046.05 211.41 1048.3 208.64 1050.15 206.38 1046.58 204.46 1042.81 202.31 1039.17 200.88 1036.62 197.77 1036.08 195.33 1034.91 193.46 1034.22 191.68 1033.04 189.63 1032.99 187.35 1034.69 186.44 1037.66 184.24 1039.47 182.15 1040.37 179.87 1041.04 177.59 1041.16 176.5 1040.2 174.91 1038.95 175.49 1037.31 176.02 1035.32 176.65 1033.34 177.4 1031.42 177.9 1030.13 179.33 1029.68 180.48 1029.13 183.69 1027.81 186.82 1026.26 190.09 1025.1 191.53 1026.03 192.85 1027.28 194.54 1027.75 195.24 1027.51 195.88 1027.1 196.43 1026.61 201.77 1021.37 207.34 1016.37 212.63 1011.08 215.8 1007.92 219.49 1005.24 222.25 1001.71 222.9 998.68 222.25 995.5 222.68 992.43 225.85 991.8 229.12 991.46 232.07 990.04 234.74 988.76 237.62 987.89 240.14 986.33 242.05 984.46 240.59 981.22 241.89 979.11 246.15 975.74 250.76 972.8 255.05 969.46 256.04 968.73 256.33 967.47 256.31 966.31 256.34 962.12 256.36 957.92 256.61 953.74 256.59 953.58 257.09 952.1 257.24 951.62 257.67 949.61 258.22 947.65 258.89 945.72 262.91 946.24 266.7 948.01 270.76 948.27 272.71 947.48 273.9 945.59 275.43 944.23 276.96 942.54 279.03 941.16 279.84 938.95 279.44 936.38 277.38 934.4 277 931.84 277.33 930.31 277.7 927.99 279.66 927.87 286.93 926.58 294.23 925.51 301.5 924.24 303.14 923.99 304.83 923.61 306.51 923.55 307.52 923.52 308.51 923.6 309.5 923.9 310.48 924.2 310.86 924.34 312.09 924.52 314.23 924.85 316.38 925.71 318.56 925.2 319.49 925.06 320.52 924.61 321.41 925.16 324.18 926.42 326.8 928.01 329.55 929.32 331.15 930.08 332.98 929.74 334.67 929.59 341.86 928.62 349.05 927.6 356.25 926.67 357.37 926.46 358.97 926.33 359.29 925 359.56 921.69 358.4 918.46 358.36 915.16 358.25 914.28 358.97 913.67 359.48 913.07 364.66 907.39 369.85 901.72 375.05 896.07L376.5 894.47 378.42 892.74 379.71 891.18C382.17 888.32 384.55 885.4 386.49 882.17 387.82 879.81 390.14 877.96 390.68 875.21 390.31 874.95 389.55 874.41 389.18 874.15 386.56 875.7 385.15 878.56 382.63 880.22 382.24 874.38 382.25 868.51 381.98 862.67 385.18 860.67 388.44 858.76 391.71 856.87 392.63 856.27 393.67 855.77 394.35 854.87 394.66 851.29 393.97 847.71 393.92 844.12 396.6 844.13 399.35 843.86 401.97 844.58 403.46 845.59 404.61 847.01 405.95 848.19 409.18 847.17 412.16 845.49 415.41 844.57 422.33 843.78 429.36 844.19 436.26 843.38 436.36 843.1 436.53 842.52 436.63 842.23 435.44 840.38 433.91 838.78 432.63 836.99 434.57 835.83 436.62 834.87 438.68 833.93 440.65 835.87 442.54 837.9 444.45 839.91 446.06 841.31 445.33 843.65 445.44 845.52 444.51 856.14 443.38 863.18 442.25 873.79Z" class="d"></path><path d="M520.47 895.46L521.06 893.83C521.36 892.77 521.75 891.72 521.87 890.63 521.3 888.2 519.93 886.07 519.3 883.67 518.45 879.57 517.08 875.59 515.75 871.62 513.74 871 511.45 870.94 509.63 869.87 507.69 867.3 505.85 864.63 504.16 861.89 503.04 860.31 505 859.04 506.27 858.51 508.31 857.94 508.72 861.23 510.69 861.17 512.24 861.24 513.79 860.98 515.33 860.79 515.44 859.88 515.55 858.97 515.64 858.06 512.37 856.71 509 855.57 505.87 853.9 506.48 851.19 507.63 848.62 508.38 845.95 508.85 843.24 507.28 840.54 507.8 837.85 509.23 835.73 511.19 834.04 512.82 832.09 511.55 829.07 510.16 826.09 508.61 823.19 504.6 825.93 500.58 828.63 496.7 831.54 497.52 833.02 498.94 834.31 499.18 836.04 498.47 837.83 497.01 839.2 495.87 840.74 495.1 841.53 494.3 843 492.99 842.4 491.83 840.73 491 838.88 489.96 837.14 486.83 838.03 483.69 838.91 480.64 840.03 480.69 840.83 480.64 841.63 480.72 842.44 480.71 844.24 480.43 844.43 478.28 845.28 476.95 845.81 473.74 847.05 470.4 847.99 469.05 844.14 467.44 839.72 466.32 835.5 467.04 834.11 468.82 833.9 470.08 833.16 469.05 831.71 467.92 830.34 466.71 829.04 465.92 830.74 465.18 832.48 464.39 834.19 462.46 834.02 460.6 833.49 458.76 832.94 457.31 836.48 456.29 840.18 454.96 843.76 454.31 846.16 451.64 846.88 449.82 848.17 448.71 848.99 446.92 849.5 446.83 851.12 445.87 858.52 445.13 865.94 444.12 873.33 443.99 874.82 443.6 876.43 444.32 877.85 446.42 882.42 448.42 887.05 450.6 891.59 452.77 896.12 451.9 894.3 451.9 894.3S454.43 899.08 455.34 901.63C454.49 902.61 453.61 903.57 452.76 904.55 454.21 906.96 455.62 913.95 455.62 913.95 456.13 917.35 455.76 919.22 455.42 922.64 452.34 924.27 448.93 925.19 445.75 926.62 446.71 933.45 447.86 940.25 448.8 947.08 449 948.76 449.5 950.45 449.33 952.16 448.57 953.38 447.24 954.07 446.12 954.9 442.18 953.08 438.62 950.55 434.7 948.71 432.53 948.32 430.34 949.15 428.18 949.35 429.25 951.51 430.57 953.52 431.87 955.55 433.09 955.74 434.52 955.99 435.78 956.26 435.59 958.18 434.9 960.15 434.61 962.28 435.31 962.49 436.43 962.57 437.03 962.9 437.9 965.32 438.44 968.97 439.09 971.46 440.11 971.7 440.62 971 441.37 971.64 442.75 972.82 443.9 974.36 445.63 975.06 447.35 975.77 449.21 976.1 451.02 976.51 451.91 975.11 452.43 973.31 453.83 972.32 457.12 970.96 460.74 970.78 464.13 969.77 465.51 969.24 466.26 967.86 467.12 966.76 466.3 964.49 464.71 962.54 464.15 960.18 464.55 959.63 464.98 959.1 465.46 958.61 470.5 962.06 475 966.3 480.14 969.58 484.05 969.77 488.01 969.5 491.93 969.3L493.97 968.82C497.86 970.35 501.04 973.18 504.87 974.83 505.75 972.96 506.54 971.04 507.53 969.22 518.1 967.12 528.73 965.39 539.32 963.36L541.61 962.9C547.4 965.27 553.47 966.88 559.36 968.98 563.57 970.16 567.43 971.99 571.76 972.62 574.32 970.2 576.12 967.13 578.5 964.54 579.5 963.49 580.98 963.14 582.31 962.69 586.74 961.4 591.16 960.06 595.6 958.75 600.67 957.34 603.27 951.55 608.57 950.71L609.99 949.34C612.08 951.32 615.01 952.02 617.81 952.2 617.8 950.11 617.13 947.87 618.15 945.92 619.08 943.9 620.13 941.92 621.11 939.92 621.69 938.85 622.27 937.59 623.51 937.17 626.56 936.04 630.01 936.02 632.82 934.26 636.74 931.89 640.6 929.45 644.47 927 645.68 926.48 645.27 925.02 645.13 924.03 644.33 920.19 643.42 916.39 642.64 912.56 641.95 909.55 644.13 906.94 644.77 904.12 639.92 904.7 635.23 906.13 630.41 906.89 626.68 907.44 623.01 908.95 619.22 908.67 615.86 906.68 613.72 902.92 609.89 901.7 605.91 900.3 602.1 898.42 597.96 897.56 594.61 896.83 591.31 895.86 587.95 895.18 587.54 895.16 587.01 895.03 586.53 895.03 586.06 895.03 585.63 895.16 585.41 895.67 584.36 897.31 584.09 899.55 582.37 900.69 579.93 900.5 577.65 899.42 575.23 899.08 574.05 899.26 573.07 900.07 571.89 900.28 570.43 899.58 569.37 898.29 568.17 897.25 566.46 901.76 564.9 906.31 563.16 910.81 562.27 912.95 558.39 915.24 558.39 915.24 557.17 916.07 555.89 915.34 555.52 915.22 555.52 915.22 553.16 913.95 551.42 913.16 550.33 914.24 549.27 915.35 548.16 916.42 547.49 916.98 546.81 918.02 545.83 917.44 544.53 916.17 543.71 914.53 542.71 913.05 541.36 912.87 540.01 912.73 538.67 912.59 538.2 911.54 537.76 910.49 537.3 909.44 535.64 910.93 534.66 913.54 532.19 913.78 532.12 911.79 532.4 909.84 532.48 907.87 532.57 907.08 531.7 906.72 531.2 906.31 527.96 904.23 524.74 902.12 521.5 900.04 519.62 898.86 520.02 897.41 520.47 895.46ZM469.02 974.75C469.6 974.28 470.27 973.7 471.08 974.02 473.78 974.76 476.3 976.06 478.94 977.01 480.82 977.67 482.34 979.01 483.77 980.36 482.59 982.45 479.88 982.39 478.31 983.98 477.6 985.53 477.71 987.31 477.11 988.91 474.9 990.23 472.24 990.53 469.76 991.1 468.1 989.4 466.61 987.48 464.55 986.24 462.57 985.04 460.61 983.81 458.61 982.65 457.24 981.72 455.53 982.06 453.98 981.97 454.4 981.49 454.74 980.9 455.31 980.57 460.09 979.32 465.27 978.19 469.02 974.75Z" class="e"></path><path d="M494.82 624.63C495.17 625.34 497.99 626.01 497.99 626.01 499.87 626.73 501.56 627.88 503.27 628.95 500.78 630.98 497.82 632.31 495.37 634.38 494.39 635.26 495.17 636.66 495.61 637.61 502 649.54 508.39 661.47 514.73 673.44 516.45 676.82 518.6 680.01 519.89 683.6 516.73 683.42 513.58 682.99 510.44 682.68 509 682.54 507.46 682.34 506.4 681.27 503.12 678.16 500.04 674.84 496.8 671.7 495.82 670.81 494.6 669.73 493.17 670.05 490.51 670.59 487.99 671.67 485.4 672.43 480.51 674.11 475.43 675.02 470.38 676.03 468.89 676.32 473.24 677.38 475.97 678.41 476.22 677.88 478.64 675.74 480.25 676.08 484.05 675.66 491.4 672.79 490.42 673.53 489.98 673.88 496.51 676.51 497.53 681.01 497.71 681.81 509.19 689.09 510.9 692.41 509.04 693.3 504.94 699.11 502.43 702.53 501.42 701.83 498.67 695.8 496.15 689.98 493.95 684.92 492.3 683.86 491.54 683.95 489.05 683.81 487.19 689.72 486.47 690.55 485.29 691.32 480.55 695.7 477.96 699.25 475.19 700.22 472.11 700.78 470.61 701.37 469.68 701.74 473.05 695.93 469.33 694.94 468.32 695.07 463.27 695.17 461.24 694.75 460.03 695.45 456.84 700.95 456.22 701.98 455.41 703.74 448.57 700.01 447.24 701.05 445.98 703.22 445.2 704.08 443.39 706.6 442.03 708.66 438.79 707.78 437.52 709.99 434.72 714.07 432.58 718.59 429.42 722.44 426.73 721.44 424.23 719.8 421.39 719.23 415.08 719.74 408.84 720.92 402.54 721.57 397.87 714.26 394.15 709.08 389.89 701.53 389.38 700.77 388.38 698.84 387.22 698.23 384.78 696.8 382.03 695.38 380.48 692.85 377.85 688.9 375.17 685 372.44 681.12 371.28 678.95 368.51 679.82 366.51 679.47 365.93 677.83 364.81 676.11 365.4 674.32 366.14 671.98 367.07 669.7 367.88 667.38 368.93 664.23 371.66 662.63 373.63 660.15L372.48 658.72C368.42 654.53 364.69 650.03 360.81 645.67 358.64 642.97 354.79 643.3 351.75 642.34 351.4 640.6 351.14 638.85 350.79 637.12 348.42 636.84 346.05 636.87 343.68 636.82 341.71 633.96 339.99 630.94 338.53 627.8 340.55 624.4 342.14 620.72 344.5 617.55 347.17 616.29 350.18 616.04 352.92 614.99 353.9 614.77 354.06 613.74 354.06 612.9 354.02 608.99 353.15 605.1 353.43 601.18 354.02 599.07 355.42 597.3 356.43 595.38 357.36 593.95 358.03 591.92 359.97 591.67 364.19 590.73 368.39 589.76 372.64 588.94 374.81 588.36 376.12 591.09 378.14 591.13 380.67 589.87 382.63 587.73 385.12 586.4 386.64 586.26 388.16 586.68 389.66 586.85 390.19 585.67 390.55 584.39 391.27 583.3 394.16 581.32 398 581.96 401.02 583.31 402.58 584.4 403.44 586.18 404.7 587.57 406.65 590.2 409.57 590.51 412.58 591.1L425.8 585.28 448.85 586.12 454.11 578.89C460.04 581.81 464.98 585.22 470.83 588.29 472.92 589.49 473.86 591.82 475.14 593.74 481.64 604.07 488.21 614.37 494.82 624.63Z" class="f"></path><path d="M408.28 519.31L416.01 542.35 417.02 545.65C417.02 545.65 418.99 551.82 420.4 555.15 421.42 557.49 423.5 559.09 425.25 560.85 427.59 562.95 429.69 565.31 431.85 567.59L452.34 577.87C452.34 577.87 447.9 583.97 447.9 583.97L425.44 583.19 412.03 589.22C410.9 588.8 408.39 588.01 407.36 587.36 405.47 585.73 404.42 583.29 402.44 581.75 400.25 580.62 397.79 580.08 395.39 579.58 392.54 580.21 389.08 581.11 388.22 584.33 386.82 584.34 385.26 583.73 384 584.59 381.95 585.92 380.03 587.47 378.02 588.86 376.62 588.13 375.4 586.88 373.82 586.61 370.8 587.02 367.89 588.06 364.83 588.22 364.46 585.79 364.82 582.98 363.06 581.02 360.39 577.71 357.15 574.9 354.61 571.48 355.34 570.07 356.09 568.66 356.76 567.21 355.25 565.5 353.2 564.14 352.15 562.08 353.56 558.58 356.62 553.55 356.62 553.55S351.27 545.86 349.09 543C345.53 544.09 343.06 547.11 339.86 548.9 338.38 546.34 336.76 543.83 335.62 541.11 336.11 539.05 337.78 537.42 338.77 535.56 338.31 533.97 337.65 532.42 337.49 530.77 339.13 527.24 341.7 524.21 343.46 520.73 339.63 515.42 334.96 510.77 331.16 505.43 334.54 501.75 338.4 498.58 341.95 495.08 346.87 490.11 352.14 485.48 357.1 480.54 359.18 478.5 361.56 476.69 363.21 474.26 363.46 472.36 362.1 470.62 361.44 468.9 359.24 464.25 357.15 459.56 354.94 454.92 354.53 453.89 353.86 452.85 353.98 451.71 357.43 448.28 361.3 445.29 364.87 441.98 367.45 439.86 369.82 437.5 372.51 435.5 381.27 443.85 389.69 452.55 398.23 461.13 399.35 462.09 399.73 463.55 399.94 464.95 402.67 483.08 405.45 501.2 408.28 519.31Z" class="g"></path><path d="M344.65 615.13C343.3 615.62 342.8 616.03 341.58 618.13 341.58 618.13 337.81 624.38 336.37 627.77 337.63 631.71 340.2 635.2 342.45 638.67 344.56 638.75 346.68 638.61 348.78 638.96 349.68 640.48 349.08 642.61 350.17 643.97 352.7 644.98 355.54 644.95 358.05 646.04 359.36 646.93 360.32 648.22 361.37 649.4 364.44 653.09 367.87 656.49 370.73 660.35 369.01 662.26 366.73 663.87 366.02 666.46 365.11 669.44 363.59 672.25 363.03 675.33 363.22 676.96 364.78 679.66 364.97 681.28 364.97 681.28 368.18 681.47 368.34 681.48L368.84 681.48C370.35 681.44 371.16 682.92 371.96 683.97 374.83 688.15 377.67 692.35 380.57 696.51 377.88 701.07 374.81 705.4 372.06 709.93 372.59 710.82 373.14 711.69 373.68 712.58 373.24 713.41 372.68 714.85 372.68 714.85 372.42 715.87 372.28 717.92 372.45 718.49 373.81 723.74 375.17 727.68 375.69 733.09 372.43 734.68 368.96 735.9 365.93 737.91 363.11 740.66 360.77 743.89 357.84 746.53 355.06 748.64 351.51 749.52 348.85 751.79 347.89 753.82 348.6 756.44 347.37 758.31 343.79 760.57 339.95 762.46 336.11 764.24 335.2 762.1 334.16 760.03 332.9 758.07 329.86 758.54 326.79 760.63 323.72 759.27 321.67 758.6 319.54 758.17 317.46 757.59 316.52 753.91 315.84 750.17 315.06 746.46 314.57 743.33 310.98 742.67 308.88 740.88 310.21 739.67 311.67 738.62 312.9 737.32 313.73 736.62 313.65 735.2 312.68 734.67 308.46 731.23 303.67 728.53 299.55 724.96L298.1 723.08C296.73 719.74 295.28 716.39 294.63 712.82 297.98 711.18 301.57 709.96 304.7 707.92 304.78 707.65 304.95 707.13 305.03 706.87 304.27 702.6 301.83 698.81 301.01 694.56 303.53 689.45 306.13 684.34 309.11 679.47L311.3 679.44C310.46 674.91 306.44 671.72 305.37 667.26 305.16 662.5 305.48 657.74 305.73 652.99 308.92 651.23 312.23 649.69 315.45 647.99 316.5 647.45 317.75 646.41 317.21 645.08 316.25 642.02 314.32 639.3 313.71 636.11 316 634.72 318.46 633.59 320.64 632.03 321.59 631.46 321.24 630.22 320.85 629.42 319.74 627.13 318.42 624.94 317.43 622.59L316.53 620.61C313.8 621.04 311.93 623.25 309.84 624.84 308.4 623.12 307.63 620.95 306.18 619.25 305.49 619.04 304.8 618.89 304.1 618.78 301.23 622.71 298.85 627 295.68 630.7 293.82 630.87 292.69 628.38 291.91 626.93 292.23 623.75 294 620.93 294.51 617.79 294.42 616.78 293.87 616.21 292.86 616.08 290.46 616.95 288.36 618.46 286.05 619.53 284.11 616.68 282.67 613.54 280.98 610.55 276.4 602.15 271.85 593.73 267.25 585.36 266.81 584.38 266.01 583.36 266.48 582.25 267.91 577.45 269.45 572.68 270.88 567.89 272.02 563.3 275.46 559.84 278.04 556.02 280.97 552.62 281.93 548.16 283.54 544.08 284.35 542.22 284.57 539.7 286.66 538.79 290.89 536.64 295.13 534.54 299.37 532.44 300.86 531.59 302.73 531.83 304.17 530.97 312.58 523.01 320.96 515.02 329.36 507.05 333.5 511.45 337.17 516.24 341.05 520.86 339.42 523.73 337.46 526.4 335.82 529.26 334.58 531.23 336.36 533.35 336.37 535.41 335.55 537.25 334.04 538.7 333.31 540.59 333.37 541.64 333.97 542.54 334.42 543.47 335.97 546.23 337.4 549.08 339.22 551.67 342.53 550.02 345.21 547.38 348.36 545.46 350.45 548.05 352.24 550.85 354.13 553.58 352.76 556.65 350.52 559.44 349.9 562.78 350.82 564.76 352.78 566.05 354.18 567.71 353.65 569.13 352.12 570.51 352.47 572.05 355.07 576.04 358.99 578.99 361.8 582.82 362.85 584.69 362.51 586.94 362.66 589 360.92 589.37 359.12 589.6 357.49 590.32 355.93 591.58 355.23 593.57 354.16 595.21 353.16 597.16 351.65 598.93 351.27 601.12 351.23 605.13 351.85 609.12 352 613.13 349.35 613.93 346.63 614.51 344.65 615.13Z" class="d"></path><path d="M349.82 758.11C349.43 759.25 348.83 759.92 347.58 760.6 343.38 762.57 339.63 765.14 335.35 766.95 334.11 764.91 333.09 762.77 332.09 760.61 329.96 760.93 327.86 761.48 325.82 762.2 325.82 764.49 326.62 766.97 325.72 769.14 323.83 770.83 321.33 771.85 318.89 772.47 316.63 770.86 315.87 767.97 314.35 765.75 310.61 766.22 306.9 766.9 303.18 767.51 301.74 767.79 299.89 767.94 299.25 769.52 297.75 772.48 296.01 775.34 294.87 778.48 298.69 781.6 302.97 784.09 306.74 787.28 305.98 790.92 304.07 794.15 302.67 797.56 301.06 801.44 299.08 805.17 297.75 809.17 299.92 810.18 302.16 810.96 304.32 811.98 304.1 812.82 304.36 813.97 303.57 814.57 299.5 817.9 294.84 820.5 291.05 824.18 296.29 826.95 302.55 830.22 307.91 832.77L306.74 836.19C303.99 844.15 301.21 852.09 298.38 860.02 297.91 861.46 297.28 862.89 297.23 864.43 297.91 866.67 299.2 868.67 300.24 870.76 302.44 874.82 304.28 879.07 306.6 883.06 308.39 882.48 310.09 881.58 311.98 881.37 313.54 881.83 314.81 882.92 316.15 883.83 320.34 886.94 324.69 889.84 328.87 892.98 332.93 890.72 336.91 888.3 340.89 885.89 341.16 881.5 340.18 877.15 340.56 872.77 343.19 872.57 345.33 872.74 347.98 872.64 350.05 872.48 352.2 873.63 352.2 873.63 354.27 874.9 354.35 875.19 356.07 876.88 358.78 876.06 361.34 874.83 363.96 873.79 366.69 872.6 369.73 873.08 372.62 872.8 377.35 872.39 382.12 872.61 386.84 872.05 385.47 870.14 383.76 868.46 382.67 866.37 384.49 864.16 387.55 863.54 389.92 862.05L392.54 860.72C392.54 860.72 395.26 863.33 396.45 864.82 398.11 866.88 400.48 868.43 401.67 870.85 401.98 873.36 401.72 875.89 401.77 878.41 403.85 877.2 406.15 876.23 407.86 874.5 410.14 869.83 410.84 864.49 413.35 859.93 415.39 860.39 417.41 860.97 419.44 861.48 421.06 858.54 421.55 855.13 423.36 852.29 423.97 850.92 425.7 851.11 426.92 850.67 426.51 849.09 426.13 847.48 425.81 845.89 427 844.9 428.45 844.19 429.41 842.95 429.99 841.34 429.95 839.61 430.08 837.94 428.91 837.54 426.4 838.09 426.9 836.15 428.26 834.68 430.04 833.7 431.54 832.38 429.42 828.07 427.07 823.88 424.92 819.59 423.94 817.25 421.32 816.54 419.34 815.31 414.22 812.43 408 810.16 405.39 804.46 405.46 802.61 406.03 800.81 406.41 799 405.4 798.29 404.38 797.59 403.35 796.92L401.1 795.54C399.05 794.11 396.81 792.97 394.92 791.35 394.51 790.06 395.6 789.04 396.27 788.08 398.59 785.29 400.89 782.47 403.06 779.56 397.48 776.68 391.27 775.28 385.61 772.57 385.62 768.8 386.05 765.05 386.2 761.29 386.14 759.15 388.52 758.48 389.93 757.43 389.6 752.59 388.81 747.8 388.36 742.97 388.39 740.52 385.74 739.82 384.08 738.69 381.68 737.46 379.52 735.68 376.91 734.92 374.72 735.64 372.71 736.84 370.58 737.7 364.92 739.7 362.75 746.06 357.84 749.1 355.42 750.41 352.92 751.57 350.53 752.94 350.27 754.67 350.05 756.54 349.82 758.11Z" class="e"></path><path d="M636.99 803.5C637.21 804.81 637.69 807.08 638.27 810.87S637.57 818.34 636.71 821.98C634.43 832.88 631.84 843.72 629.53 854.62 629.21 855.93 628.97 857.38 627.97 858.38 623.55 863.03 618.75 867.29 614.39 872.01 613.09 873.65 611.07 875.32 609.51 877.11 607.94 878.89 605.83 880.31 604.8 882.5 604.55 884.75 607.34 884.75 608.81 885.49 605.86 888.52 602.92 891.64 599.52 894.14 594.29 895.36 588.77 894.44 583.48 895.41 582.67 895.76 582.31 896.38 582.41 897.27 583.39 899.41 586.11 900.78 585.78 903.43 585.71 906.72 586.04 910.05 585.56 913.31 583.58 916.69 580.87 919.59 578.6 922.79 577.54 924.1 576.53 925.88 574.63 925.94 569.53 926.48 564.42 926.93 559.32 927.4 557.83 927.6 556.22 927.32 554.86 928.05 553.32 930.3 552.59 932.99 551.2 935.33 548.5 934.94 545.94 933.91 543.24 933.52 542.16 933.73 541.21 934.29 540.23 934.73 539.02 933.65 537.81 932.58 536.7 931.42 538.49 929.01 540.75 926.98 542.38 924.45 541.65 920.75 540.14 917.11 538.25 913.83 534.59 914.61 530.96 915.54 527.35 916.53 526.44 916.67 525.37 917.23 524.54 916.57 522.77 915.29 520.99 913.98 519.51 912.39 519.28 911.93 519.2 911.01 519.07 910.16 518.76 907.84 518.79 907.78 516.16 907.94 513.48 908.17 510.73 907.75 508.09 908.29 503.24 910.79 498.86 914.14 494.01 916.64 490.86 917.66 487.48 917.58 484.23 918.07 482.14 913.6 481.52 908.6 479.45 904.13 477.35 901.96 473.15 903.34 471.43 900.52 469.8 898.03 466.06 893.72 467.15 893.08 467.89 892.27 469.21 894.72 470.4 895.61 473.2 896.09 476.27 895.25 479.09 895.12L479.68 888.83C476.28 887.33 472.64 886.02 469.25 884.5 470 881.73 471.23 879.1 471.83 876.29 471.86 873.97 471.1 871.73 470.96 869.43 470.71 868.09 472.02 867.29 472.75 866.38 474.11 864.78 475.99 863.48 476.73 861.46 475.38 857.06 472.63 853.24 471.2 848.87 471.15 846.86 472.08 844.95 472.47 843 474.66 843.39 477.01 843.71 479.23 843.92 479.83 842.25 480.92 839.4 481.59 838.98 482.28 838.08 483.62 837.77 483.62 837.77 484.4 837.29 484.23 836.4 483.9 834.8 483.55 833.47 483.07 831.81 482.81 830.29 485.66 828.07 488.9 826.34 491.59 823.94 492.74 820.96 492.65 817.63 492.9 814.47 491.36 813.37 489.81 812.28 488.29 811.16 488.13 809.34 488.04 807.51 487.93 805.69 486.36 805.49 484.78 805.35 483.21 805.16 482.98 803.64 482.83 802.38 482.73 800.84 487.33 799.13 491.97 796.05 497.05 796.32 502.01 796.38 506.74 796.14 511.7 796.22 514.05 796.24 517.69 797.16 518.36 797.96 519.37 795.04 519.92 791.99 520.92 789.06 522.94 788.66 525.29 788.24 527.22 787.96 530.74 787.24 531.37 785.82 531.79 785.42 534.1 782.85 533.63 782.81 535.9 780.21 537.98 781.08 539.84 782.44 542 783.11 543.54 783.25 543.89 781.44 544.52 780.41 547.27 774.02 549.92 767.6 552.6 761.19 553.04 760.17 553.64 758.8 555.01 759.04 563.86 758.98 572.71 759.06 581.57 759.02 588.35 758.69 594.91 760.78 601.56 761.75 604.55 762.5 608.07 762.24 610.44 764.54 617.15 770.18 623.77 775.93 630.49 781.58 631.97 782.9 633.95 784.14 634.19 786.31 635.14 792.03 636.12 797.76 636.99 803.5Z" class="d"></path></svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, попробую.

Comment: Вставляю svg а она прозрачная. В чем может быть причина, не подскажете?

Comment: @Александр, в том, что фон не задан. Вот на первой попавшейся карте: https://jsfiddle.net/u0csprkn/ - в ответ не лезет, т. к. данных уйма...

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю обойтись area

Есть плюс в том, что можно использывать href=

вот пример:

[Пример при навидении](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html)

Как создавать map area:
[Генератор для создания при помощи наложения рисунков](http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de)

Наберите в гугле или яндексе map area html и найдёте кучу примеров